# Add custom framework to Standard Library in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I've looked everywhere and no article gives me exactly the solution I'm looking for.

Is there a way to "install" a custom framework into Xcode?
For example, let's say I've created a framework called 'MyAwesomeFramework' which is really reusable (for example contains a lot of useful UIView extensions). Now what I want to do is be able to just create any new project and type `import MyAwesomeFramework` to use it, instead of having to add the respective Xcode Project to the project I want to use it in.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/InstallingFrameworks.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different options. You can manually add them via drag and drop or use one of many framework managers such as Carthage or Cocoapods.

Whatever method you choose has a few steps and can be a bit daunting initially so I’d recommend following a tutorial of some sort(I used YouTube). If done correctly you will be able to just import like you would do any other library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I know how to use CocoaPods/Carthage and that is not quite what I wanted. I ended up manually add it via drag-and-drop

Comment: I would like to test your recommendation "You can manually add them via drag and drop", but from where? I can't locate my "framework binary". It shows only up, when I add the whole framework project into the app project, where it should be used. But how to add the framework binary only?